# PHP session expires while in use

Tags: php, session

Recently my webhost changed the PHP configuration. The only complaint I have is that sessions expire while in use.

Generally, I just write once to the session, but read many times, so I thought this may be because the filemtime wasn't changing, so every time I read, I also write by incrementing a counter. Still nothing, after 24 minutes, whether the session is being used or not, it gets cleared.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You could set up a your own [`session.save_path`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to a dir under your control. But really, your webhost should fix this themselves asap.

Comment: BTW: it seriously sounds like they've mounted a disk with `noatime` option.. Which indeed, would let PHP time out the session. Tell them that, and ask for a session save path on a disk _with_ atime.

Answer (score 0):

PHP constantly reads and writes the session data file when you start a session and end the script (or call `session_write_close()`), so the file mtime should change. There is no need to change the atime option of the filesystem.

But things can easily go wrong beyond that, including having strange cronjob scripts running that delete session files. Without you complaining at the service desk, they will never fix it.